Updating Vite to its latest version in package.json is not updating its dependencies in package-lock.json
In package.json, I have upgraded Vite to its latest version - 5.4.0.
But package-lock.json is still showing dependencies with its old version -
esbuild latest version in npm registry is 0.23.0 but here in package-lock.json is 0.21.3

Am I missing something? I have already deleted the node_modules and package-lock.json before running npm install

Those are Vite's dependencies, per its own package file. It doesn't ask for the latest version; 0.23.0 isn't compatible with ^0.21.3.


Revert the packages.json to before the update.
Install globally npm-check-updates
Run npm-check-updates

This should update Vite and all other dependent packages.
